# Apply the Random Forest Algorithm to a Dataset containing missing values

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, mlr

I would like to apply the Random Forest algorithm from the package `mlr` to a data set. This is the `Zoo` dataset from the package `mlbench`.

```
data(Zoo, package = "mlbench")
zooTib <- as_tibble(Zoo)
zooTib <- mutate_if(zooTib, is.logical, as.factor)
```

But before that I have introduced random NAs, only the target variable `type` I have left complete.

```
zooTibOrig <- zooTib
zooTib <- apply (zooTib[,1:ncol(zooTib)-1], 2, function(x) {x[sample( c(1:nrow(zooTib)), floor(nrow(zooTib)/10))] <- NA; x} )
zooTib <- cbind(zooTib, zooTibOrig[,ncol(zooTibOrig)])
zooTib
```

Before testing the random forest algorithm, I ran the zoo dataset with the NAs through a simple RPART decision tree algorithm.  This has the possibility to process datasets with NAs due to its parameters "maxsurrogate" or "usesurroagte". So I could pass the dataset without any problems and the code was executed without any problems.

Next I wanted to use the above mentioned random forest algorithm.

```
forest <- makeLearner("classif.randomForest")
forestParamSpace <- makeParamSet(makeIntegerParam("ntree", lower = 300, upper = 300), makeIntegerParam("mtry", lower = 6, upper = 12), makeIntegerParam("nodesize", lower = 1, upper = 5), makeIntegerParam("maxnodes", lower = 5, upper = 20))
randSearch <- makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 100)
cvForTuning <- makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 5)

tunedForestPars <- tuneParams(forest, task = zooTask,
                          resampling = cvForTuning,
                          par.set = forestParamSpace,
                          control = randSearch)
```

However, as soon as I wanted to run the parameter tuning process I got the error message:

> "Error in checkLearnerBeforeTrain(task, learner, weights) :    Task
> 'zooTib' has missing values in 'hair, feathers, eggs, milk, airborne,
> aquatic, ...', but learner 'classif.randomForest' does not support
> that!"

This is strange, since a Random Forest is "merely" an ensemble of several Decision Trees - which in turn can handle Missing Values. I acutally tried it before and the RPART algorithm worked perfectly fine.

I wanted to try to set the Surrogate Split parameter, but for a Random Forest this setting does not exist. When I execute the function `getParamSet(forest)` unfortunately no surrogate splits appear there.

Is there  a possibility to somehow pass records containing NAs to a random forest.

Comment: Why not do missing value imputation?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thank you for your reply! I've read previously that random forests can handle missing data on their own - like XGBoost for example. Sure, I could impute the missing values ... but why should I, if it's supposed to work also with missing values?

Comment: Just declare missings as a specific factor level in your predictors, then you should be fine.

Comment: For numeric ones, I‘m not sure, though.

Comment: [See if this question and answer helps.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68954983/missing-value-error-although-na-action-was-set-to-na-roughfix)